# How to add a custom geolocate me button in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, icontrol

I am trying to add a custom Geolocate me button to my map and it kind of works, however only if I also add the standard icon from Mapbox. The code below works, but if I remove the line `map.addControl(geolocate, 'top-right');`, my left button stops working.

```
      // Initialize the geolocate control.
  var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
      trackUserLocation: true
    });
    // Add the control to the map.
  map.addControl(geolocate, 'top-right');

  class ToggleControl {

    constructor(options) {
      this._options = Object.assign({}, this._options, options)
    }

    onAdd(map, cs) {
      this.map = map;
      this.container = document.createElement('div');
      this.container.className = `${this._options.className}`;

      const button = this._createButton('monitor_button')
      this.container.appendChild(button);
      return this.container;
    }
    onRemove() {
      this.container.parentNode.removeChild(this.container);
      this.map = undefined;
    }
    _createButton(className) {
      const el = window.document.createElement('button')
      el.className = className;
      el.textContent = 'Use my location';
      el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      geolocate.trigger();
      }, false)
      return el;
    }
  }
  const toggleControl = new ToggleControl({
    className: 'mapboxgl-ctrl'
  })
  map.addControl(toggleControl, 'top-left')
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbBrN.png) - in blue is what I want to keep, in Red to remove

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl Instance, you can extend mapboxgl.GeolocateControl Class like below:

```
class ToggleControl extends mapboxgl.GeolocateControl {
            _onSuccess(position) {
                this.map.flyTo({
                    center: [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude],
                    zoom: 17,
                    bearing: 0,
                    pitch: 0
                });
            }

            onAdd(map, cs) {
                this.map = map;
                this.container = document.createElement('div');
                this.container.className = `mapboxgl-ctrl`;
                const button = this._createButton('monitor_button')
                this.container.appendChild(button);
                return this.container;
            }

            _createButton(className) {
                const el = window.document.createElement('button')
                el.className = className;
                el.textContent = 'Use my location';
                el.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    this.trigger();
                });
                this._setup = true;
                return el;
            }
        }
        const toggleControl = new ToggleControl({})
        map.addControl(toggleControl, 'top-left')
```

Other Helpful links:

- Mapbox gl Class URL: Have a look https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/520a4ca3b9d260693f1e7f4af30d8b91c8f8bb08/src/ui/control/geolocate_control.js#L97-L565
- [How to wrap a ui control (mapbox geolocation control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541069/how-to-wrap-a-ui-control-mapbox-geolocation-control)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add custom button in mapBox . [image]

add some css:

```
    .map_btn{position: absolute; top: 25;  width: 36px;height:36px;border-radius:50%;border:none;float:right;margin-right:5px;zindex:111;left:85%;background:#e8faa7;}
```

add the button

```
               <button class="map_btn"><img src="loc1.png" width=30/> 
               </button>
                <div id="map"></div>
```

Add your code to your button

```
$('.map_btn').click(function(e)
{
    app.preloader.show();
    getLocation() ;
});
```